# Adding open graph info to a hosted pdf file?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, pdf, facebook-opengraph

Bit of an amateur here, so I apologize in advance if this question is something that I should know, but don't. I am trying to find out if there is a way to add Open Graph info to pdf files that I have hosted inside my public_html folder.

To clarify, I have a wordpress site, and in it I have a page called "knowledge base" that has portfolio items that link to various helpful PDF files that I FTP'd into that wordpress folder. I realized stupidly, when I tried to share a link to the file on Facebook, that no image or description or title shows up. Is there any way to mitigate this? Can I add more info into the shareable URL? Can I add metadata into the PDF?  Can I link to another page and somehow put the metadata there but then have it automatically redirect to the PDF link?

I will preface that I am not a programmer, so please be easy on me.  Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: No, you can not embed HTML meta tags into a PDF. Yes, you can create a page that has OG meta tags, and redirects human visitors elsewhere. (Either go research that on your own, or hire a developer.)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Appreciate it.